# create an action of UI label in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making an inbox module in my app.On first load 20 messages are coming from server.
I want that after 20 messages a label named "load more messages" will be create in UItableview cell.
and after clicking on that label i want to make another call to server. 
I had tried following code but it is not working . thanx in advance:(
[image: It is showing like this i want to show it after recprds has been laoded]
below is my sample code of cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [inboxmessagesarray count]+1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *tableviewidentifier = @"cell";
   __block  tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [self.activitiesTableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
    }if(indexPath.row == [self tableView:self.activitiesTableView_ numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] - 1){
        cell.textLabel.text=@"Load More Record";// here i am making a label but it is not showing at the end of tableview cell



    }
    else{

     __block NSString *row = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    cell.titlename.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:15];
    cell.tolbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:12];
    cell.fromlbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:12];
    cell.datelbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:8];
    cell.timelbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:8];
      if([[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageRead"] intValue]==0)
    {

        cell.titlename.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:15];
        cell.tolbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:12];
        cell.fromlbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:12];
        cell.datelbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:8];
        cell.timelbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:8];

                cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];



    }
    else
    {
        cell.titlename.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI" size:15];
        cell.tolbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:12];
        cell.fromlbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:12];
        cell.datelbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:8];
        cell.timelbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"SegoeUI-light" size:8];

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    }
    cell.titlename.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];
   //toCity

    cell.tolbl.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"toCity"];
    cell.fromlbl.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"fromCity"];
    if(![[imagesDictionary allKeys] containsObject:row]) //if image not found download and add it to dictionary
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            NSString *img=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"offerPhoto"];// here i am getting image path
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:img];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //in main thread update the image
                 [imagesDictionary setObject:image forKey:row];
                cell.profileimage.image = image;
                cell.textLabel.text = @""; //add this update will reflect the changes
                NSLog(@"loading and adding to dictionary");
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        cell.profileimage.image = [imagesDictionary objectForKey:row];
        NSLog(@"retriving from dictionary");
    }


    cell.datelbl.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageDate"];
    cell.timelbl.text=[[self.inboxmessagesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"messageTime"];
    }

return cell;
}
```

Comment: you have to add tap gesture to label. after that you will be able to perform an action (do what ever you want in calback method)

Comment: label is not showing properly ... u can read my complete question'

Comment: and please also screenshot i want to show that label or button at the end of messages when messages has been loaded after that i ant to show

Comment: Add it to your tableview footer this can be done in storyboard or pragmatically, that way you don't have to worry about constraints or auto layout affecting your labels frame and origins

Comment: @soulshined i am unable to get u i just want this label at the end of messages

Comment: which type u need the answer, already u have a all datas in **inboxmessagesarray** no need to call after 21 time

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i want to show these 'Load more records' label at the end of last row of tableview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik u got that ?

Comment: @MishalAwan check my answer it is working fine in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this in multiple types here I add  in 3 types, customize your self

**choice No 1**

assume that u get the all data (e.g 100) from server , store in the some `NSMutableArray`, concept is declare one global `int`

```
 int loadMoreItems;
```

in your `viewWillAppear`

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  loadMoreItems=21; // initially set the count is more than 20
 }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
if ([yourTotalArrayName count]<=loadMoreItems) {
        return [yourTotalArrayName count];
    }
    else {
        return loadMoreItems;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier;

 // add your data

 if (indexPath.row+1<loadMoreItems)
            {

      cell.lblLoadMoreItems.hidden=YES;
     cell.itemsdetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[yourTotalArrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;
     }
else

  {
      cell.itemsdetails.hidden=YES;
      cell.lblLoadMoreItems.text = @"Load more results...!";

  }
 }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

  if (indexPath.row+1<loadMoreItems) {
  // here do your stuff here 


   }
    else {
        loadMoreItems=loadMoreItems+20;
        [self.yourtableview reloadData];
    }
```

**choice no 2**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Classic start method

 // here add your data loaded

if (indexPath.row == [self.yourarrayName count] - 1)
{
    cell.lblLoadMoreItems.text = @"Load more results...!";
    [self launchReload];
 }
}



  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   if (indexPath.row == [self.yourarrayName count] - 1)
 {

    [self launchReload];
 }

 }



  -(void)launchRelaod

 {
 // call the webservice

  [self.yourtableview reloadData];
 }
```

**choiceNo 3**

```
  use 2 prototype cell in `UItableView`

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  return [yourarrayname count] + 1;
  }


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *postCellId = @"postCell";  
 static NSString *moreCellId = @"moreCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;



if ([indexPath row] == [yourarrayname count]) {

  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:moreCellId];

  if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:moreCellId];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = @"Load more items...";
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];


} 
else 
 {
  cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:postCellId];
  if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:postCellId];
  }

   // show your Data
 }

return cell;
}



 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

  if ([indexPath row] == [yourarrayname count]) {

    // call the web service and reload Data of UItableview
   }
 else

  {
    //normall selcftion procedure
 }

}
```

Comment: wait I upload the option 2

Answer (score 1):

try to use following `Methods` of `UITableView`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIView * viewHeader = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    [viewHeader setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIButton * btnLoadMore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnLoadMore setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 30)];
    [btnLoadMore setTitle:@"Load More Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnLoadMore setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [btnLoadMore setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btnLoadMore addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMoreRecords:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewHeader addSubview:btnLoadMore];
    return viewHeader;
}

- (void)loadMoreRecords : (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Your code to load more data");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As u want a row to be added to tableview that shows `Load More Records` u can do it in 2 ways either by adding a footer view or every last row, by passing one extra row in the method `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` and return a particular cell for this row in `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

for example add one more custom cell in the tableview and add a label and set its text as `Load more record` and set its reuse identifier as `LabelCell`

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return self.inboxmessagesarray.count + 1 ;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
   //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:tableView];
   if(indexPath.row == [self.inboxmessagesarray count])
   {
      NSLog(@"load more records");
   }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  __block  tablecellTableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
  if(cell == nil)
  {
      cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableviewidentifier];
  }
  //in the last row
  if(indexPath.row == self.inboxmessagesarray.count)
  {
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LabelCell"];
      if(cell == nil)
      {
          cell = [[tablecellTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"LabelCell"];
      }
      if([self.inboxmessagesarray count] > 0)
          cell.hidden = NO;
      else
          cell.hidden = YES;

      return cell;
  }
  //..rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your label as a Table's footerview.

```
tableview.tableFooterView = label;
```

By this you will get your label at the end of your table always.

And for load more action add tap gestures to the label.

Comment: @ Mishal Awan on an action are you requesting to the server again or you had got all the data in your inboxmessagesarray?

Comment: yeah i have to reload data on it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something to show up at the bottom or below your tableView you just implement a quick step:

This will waive any auto layout woes or troubles with a UILabels frame or origins (it will never move)

```
UIView* footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 25)];
UIButton *loadMoreButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25)];
[loadMoreButton setTitle:@"Load More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loadMoreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMore:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//More customizing
[footerView addSubview:loadMoreButton];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;

-(IBAction)loadMoreButton:(id)sender {
//load more from server 
}
```

Comment: i want to show this footer when all the messages has been loaded ?

Comment: @MishalAwan You can put it in a void function and call it when all the messages have been loaded like you want. Thats the easy part. I don't know how you set up your tableView but just add it to wherever you create your cells and once they are all created and loaded then display the footerView